# Correlated diffusion processes and covariance matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, correlation, stochastic-calculus

I'm really noob in maths topics so I hope you will excuse me if I use terms which aren't correct.

I would like to simulate $n$ dimensional diffusion processes with $n$ noises.

Each process has its variance and is correlated to others by correlation / covariance matrix.

My question is about the diffusion matrix: how is it linked to the correlation / covariance matrix?

Let I have martingales

$\begin{pmatrix}
dX_{t}^{1}\\ 
dX_{t}^{2}
\end{pmatrix} = 0+\begin{pmatrix}
\cdots  & \cdots \\ 
\cdots  & \cdots 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
dW_{t}^{1}\\ 
dW_{t}^{2}
\end{pmatrix}$.

What should I use instead of the empty diffusion matrix if my correlation / covariance matrix is like

$V=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -.1\\
-.1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$?

Thanks,

Comment: I believe the lower triangular matrix in the Cholesky decomposition of $V$ would work.